# Charging behavior of iOS devices

Tags: iphone, battery

Does the speed at which the battery of an iOS device charges vary depending upon whether it is being used or not?
For example, when I am charging an iPhone in my car, will it charge faster when not in use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes if you use it, it takes longer to charge because your usage consumes power as well. OTOH I doubt whether you will notice a huge difference when you only have 20 minutes left to charge.

Comment: I thought maybe the power supply supplies more power to the battery than it can absorb and therefore the rest of the power is used to the current usage of the device.

Comment: It depends on the device, but patrix is right. It's less noticeable on something like an iPod Touch, but on a Retina iPad (where the screen draws a lot of power), the charging process is considerably slower if you're using the screen while charging.